# Rotate text box direction in draw.io

Tags: text, app.diagrams.net

In draw.io I have text box with default text direction horizontal.  I am trying change the text direction to vertical or trying to rotate the text box 90 degrees.  I don't find any option do that.

Could anybody point me to how to do that?

Comment: :)  Arrange --> direction -> Rotate

Comment: There will be rotation handles on shapes by next week, then you can rotate in the normal way for such applications.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of rotating the text inside a box, you can rotate the box with handle then use 'rotate shape only' button in 'arrange' tab

[image: Rotate shape only button in arrange tab draw.io]

As below,

[image]

Comment: This is great when it's a built-in shape - but if it's a group, it acts strange and not as expected.

Comment: Looks like this option "Rotate shape only by 90°" does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Also: Text, Alignment, Vertical - A rotation handle has also been added.

In addition, on the "Text" pane, there is a button with 3 up arrows you can use to switch between text directions:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the rotation handle on shape:

[image]